# My code keeps returning undefined underneath the output

Tags: javascript, function

My JavaScript function keeps returning `undefined` underneath the correct output value.

```
let grade;

function getGrade(score) {
    // Write your code here
    if (score >= 25 && score <= 30) {
        console.log('A');
    }
    else if (score >= 20 && score <= 25) {
        console.log('B');
    }
    else if (score >= 15 && score <= 20) {
        console.log('C');
    }
    else if (score >= 10 && score <= 15) {
        console.log('D');
    }
    else if (score >= 5 && score <= 10) {
        console.log('E');
    }
    else {
        console.log('F');
    }
    return grade;
}
```

Comment: What is expected output and what is input?

Comment: that's because you haven't defined what `grade` is. You can set it in your if statements, then `return`

Comment: you're returning `grade` but where do you declare it and populate it?

Comment: even after declaring `let grade;` outside what do you do with it .. why shouldn't it return undefined?

Comment: OP did declare `grade` but it had been omitted from the code block because the markup was missing a newline after the three ```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined your `grade`. And it will always be `undefined`.

One way to do it is as follows:

```js
function getGrade(score) {
    var grade = "";
    // Write your code here
    if (score >= 25 && score <= 30) {
        grade = "A";
    }
    else if (score >= 20 && score <= 25) {
        grade = "B";
    }
    else if (score >= 15 && score <= 20) {
        grade = "C";
    }
    else if (score >= 10 && score <= 15) {
        grade = "D";
    }
    else if (score >= 5 && score <= 10) {
        grade = "E";
    }
    else {
        grade = "F";
    }
    return grade;
}

console.log(getGrade(27))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have `return grade;` at the bottom, but `grade` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should to set your variable "grade" value, or just delete

```
return grade;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `return` instead of `console.log()`

```js
function getGrade(score) {
    if (score >= 25 && score <= 30) {
        return 'A'
    }
    else if (score >= 20 && score <= 25) {
        return 'B'
    }
    else if (score >= 15 && score <= 20) {
        return 'C';
    }
    else if (score >= 10 && score <= 15) {
        return 'D';
    }
    else if (score >= 5 && score <= 10) {
        return 'E';
    }
    else {
        return 'F';
    }
}
console.log(getGrade(20))
```

As there is difference of `5` b/w each grade range so you can use division and `Math.floor`

```js
function getGrade(score) {
    let grades = 'FEDCBA' 
    return score === 30 ? 'A' : grades[Math.floor((score)/5)]    
}
console.log(getGrade(20))
console.log(getGrade(19))
console.log(getGrade(30))
```

Answer (score 1):

Always check the console. It's currently singing at you, telling you `grade` is undefined.

You're trying to return something you haven't assigned a value to.

```
function getGrade(score) {
    // ... //
    return grade; //<-- nowhere do you define grade
}
```

Should be

```
function getGrade(score) {
    let grade;
    if (score >= 25 && score <= 30) grade = 'A';
    else if (score >= 20 && score <= 25) grade = 'B';
    else if (score >= 15 && score <= 20) grade = 'C';
    else if (score >= 10 && score <= 15) grade = 'D';
    else if (score >= 5 && score <= 10) grade = 'E';
    else grade = 'F';
    console.log(grade);
    return grade;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot Sir, i got it now.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept one of the answers if you consider it to be correct.